# Javascript get ref to Array.forEach

Tags: javascript

Simple question - why

```
[1,2,3,4].forEach(console.log)
```

works fine,

```
let g = f => [1,2,3,4].forEach(f);
g(console.log);
```

works fine, but

```
let h = [1,2,3,4].forEach;
h(console.log)
```

throws Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined
?

Comment: Try `let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4], h = arr.forEach.bind(arr);`

Comment: Your first two examples are equivalent shorthand for `[1,2,3].forEach(e => console.log(e))`. The last example doesn't _invoke_ `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: Hi I think that ```forEach``` expect a callback as a parameter, In your first and second functions you are passing that, ```console.log```, and ```f``` as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let x = [1,2,3,4];
let h = x.forEach.bind(x);
h(console.log)
```

It's because the `forEach` function gets unbound when you assign it to a variable. That's why this code works

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/

Answer (score 2):

You are only taking the function `forEach` from the array, but you need to bind the array for iterating this array ([`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)).

Only this step takes the array as `this` for the array method.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    h = Array.prototype.forEach.bind(array);

h(console.log);
```